# How to filter inside For loop with OR condition?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I use an Or condition inside a For loop?

I have an Excel document with over 40 sheets.

Right now my code will display only the rows with "dogs" in column N.

I want to display the rows that have "cats" Or "dogs" in column N.

```
Sub apply_autofilter_across_worksheets()
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160623
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each xWs In Worksheets
        xWs.Range("N1").AutoFilter 14, "=dogs"
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to have multiple filter conditions is to build an array. Try the below.

```
Sub apply_autofilter_across_worksheets()
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160623
    Dim xWs As Worksheet, FltrArray() As Variant

    FltrArray = Array("Dogs", "Cats", "EveryOtherAnimals")

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each xWs In Worksheets
        xWs.Range("N1").AutoFilter 14, Criteria1:=FltrArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Next xWs
End Sub
```

Add or Remove your criteria stored in the array according to your requirement.

Comment: Sweet. When I ran this it worked. Is it possible to filter not so specifically? For example, If I had "Big Dogs" and "Little Dogs" they don't show up using this method. Is there a way to make all dogs show up by just putting "dogs" or do I have to specify each type?

Comment: Glad it worked. Try adding wild card to the array list. Ex. FltrArray = Array("*Dogs*", "Cats", "EveryOtherAnimals"). Note the Star(*) before and after dogs.

Answer (score 0):

Try code bellow:

```
xWs.Range("N1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=cats", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=dogs"
```